# How to fix OOM exception for my apache ignite 2.7.0?

Tags: java, out-of-memory, ignite

We got several times of OOM exceptions for our apache ignite 2.7.0, which is deploy by docker.

### I found this log message:

### Message queue limit is set to 0 which may lead to potential OOMEs when running cache operations in FULL ASYNC or PRIMARY_SYNC modes due to message queues growth on sender and receiver sides.

And I found message about this at https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/clients-vs-servers#section-managing-slow-clients.

So, I want reproduce the OOM exception ,then modify the configuration to make sure that I fix OOM in right way.
But I can't reproduce the OOM exception, so How can I reproduce it?

The other question is:  What's the default expire time ?
Cause I did not get the default expire time at https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/expiry-policies.

Any helpers will be appreciated.

### Below is my current configuration:

```
    <bean id="ignite.cfg" class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">
        <property name="cacheConfiguration">
            <list>
                <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration">
                    <property name="name" value="name"/>
                    <property name="atomicityMode" value="ATOMIC"/>
                    <property name="cacheMode" value="REPLICATED"/>
                </bean>
                        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration">
                    <property name="name" value="session"/>
                    <property name="atomicityMode" value="ATOMIC"/>
                    <property name="cacheMode" value="REPLICATED"/>
                </bean>
            </list>
        </property>

        <property name="peerClassLoadingEnabled" value="true"/>

        <property name="discoverySpi">
            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi">
                <property name="ipFinder">
                    <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.vm.TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder">
                        <property name="addresses">
                            <list>
                                <value>10.130.221.31</value>
                                <value>10.130.223.32:47500..47509</value>
                            </list>
                        </property>
                    </bean>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Answer (score 3):

Please keep in mind that the log message actually says:

> Message queue limit is set to 0 which **may** lead to potential OOMEs

<sup>highlight mine^</sup>

This communicates the fact that nodes in cluster have queues for inter-node communication. They used to be bound but now they are set to 0 denoting **no limit**. So if one node was slow, others sending it messages could end up backing these up **without limit** which could lead to OOMEs.

You can set it in code by calling `TcpCommunicationSPI.setMessageQueueLimit()` or 
`<property name="messageQueueLimit" value="1024"/>` in [TcpCommunicationSpi](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/clustering/network-configuration?#communication).

Answer (score 0):

Your OOM is likely not related to Apache Ignite, since it does not usually consume too much heap (how much is there, anyway?).

But you can only figure it out by collecting a heap dump and checking it for suspicious things using a heap analyzer.